# Как отсортировать массив по количеству дубликатов?

Tags: python-2.7

подскажите какие в питоне есть инструменты для того чтобы отсортировать массив таким образом, чтобы сначала шли самые часто повторяющиеся значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Counter

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter()
l = [4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 5]

for x in l:
    c[x] += 1

print(c.most_common())

>>[(5, 4), (4, 2), (3, 2), (2, 1), (6, 1)]
```